# Django rest framework hyperlinkrelatedfield for one table using primary key

Tags: django, hyperlink, django-rest-framework

I have a table called 'users' and 'location'. Users table has a foreign key that relates to location table. I have a users serializer to get the JSON. What would I do to get the hyperlinks for the users table using its primary key?

In django rest framework documentation, I couldn't find a solution. I tried using hyperlinkrelatedfield. But still I couldn't achieve this. Can someone help me in finding the solution?

Comment: Just to confirm in the User json response, you want a link of that user entity?

Comment: Yes. URL like http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/{userid}. It should give the JSON of the user whose userid is specified in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Using `rest-framework` `HyperlinkedRelatedField` does not work because it was never built to expose the URL of the object being requested. Mainly because since the client already has the url of the user, why send it back again? Nevertheless you can achieve this by doing something like this.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def get_label_location(self, obj):
        return HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='user-detail',
                                   read_only=True) \
        .get_url(obj, view_name='label-detail',
                 request=self.context['request'], format=None)
```

Take note on a few things,

1. `view-name` param to the `HyperlinkedRelatedField` should be based on your url configuration
2. `read-only` has to be true since otherwise you'll have to specify the queryset. But since we have the object needed to generate the url we can ignore that.
3. I've set `format` param to `None` but you might want to set it based on your settings.

You can read up about `SerializerMethodField` [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).